# How to pass date into picker view in ios

Tags: ios, xcode, nsdate, uipickerview

I just want to pass date in to picker view and other next component I want to pass another array. But for first component of rows I need to show date in picker view.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two separate picker views, a UIDatePicker, and a UIPickerView. Read up on the documentation of the UIPickerViewDelegate and UIPickerViewDataSource to populate it with your array.

Comment: Is it not possible to pass NSDate to pickerview to display date.?

Comment: I suppose you could generate a whole bunch of NSDates and convert them to strings, put them in an array, and add them to the UIPickerView but I would recommend against that strongly.

Comment: No, I dont want to pass it through manually of dates. user wants to add any date and any year in the NSDate. I need only Date as NSDate and another 3 elements array.